# Implementing the defer keyword in C

Tags: c, macros, function-pointers, alloca

Golang has a useful language construct called [`defer`](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/12) which allows the user to postpone a function's execution until the surrounding function returns. This is useful for ensuring that resources are safely destroyed while keeping the creation-destruction logic close together.

I am interested in implementing this through macros in C99. The following is what I have written so far, along with some example code to show the macro in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void* log_malloc(size_t size) {
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    printf("Allocated %zu bytes: %p\n", size, ptr);
    return ptr;
}

void log_free(void* ptr) {
    free(ptr);
    printf("Freed %p\n", ptr);
}

typedef void (*DeferFunc)();
typedef struct Defer {
    DeferFunc f;
    void* p;
} Defer;

#define PRE_DEFER() \
    size_t num_defers = 0; \
    Defer defers[32];

#define DEFER(func, param) \
    defers[num_defers].f = func;\
    defers[num_defers].p = param;\
    num_defers++;

#define POST_DEFER() \
    while(num_defers > 0) { \
        defers[num_defers - 1].f(defers[num_defers - 1].p); \
        num_defers--; \
    }

void test() {
    PRE_DEFER();
    char* a = log_malloc(10);
    DEFER(log_free, a);
    char* b = log_malloc(20);
    DEFER(log_free, b);
    char* c = log_malloc(30);
    DEFER(log_free, c);
    POST_DEFER();
}

int main() {
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

This code works and, in my basic benchmarking compared to just manually ordering the destructor statements, has about a 10% performance overhead. However, it is limited in the number of `DEFER` macro calls that can be handled. I can of course pass in the number of defers I expect to perform in the `PRE_DEFER` macro, but this can be tedious and error-prone to count defer calls, especially if there is branching logic or loops containing `DEFER` statements. Is there a way to programmatically populate the size of the `defers` array (as a VLA) in the generated macro code?

Solutions I have already considered or am not interested in:

- Just using C++. This could be addressed with RAII. However, the destructor logic becomes implicit, and I am simply not interested in the additional complexity/feature-creep that C++ offers.
- Using compiler extensions. GCC (and clang I believe) have an [`__attribute__ cleanup`](https://echorand.me/site/notes/articles/c_cleanup/cleanup_attribute_c.html) syntax that can be abused that performs well but is not supported in MSVC and requires modifying the supplied destructor to use a pointer to the variable rather than the variable itself.
- Using repeated `alloca` calls at each `DEFER`. This does work, but is slow (up to 2x slower than manually ordering the function calls or my current `defer` solution).

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**Update:**

Thanks to @Dai for pointing out MSVC's `__try` and `__finally` compiler constructs. Using them, I get the following code:

```
#define DEFER(fini_call, body) \
    __try{ body } \
    __finally{ fini_call; }

void test() {
    char* a = log_malloc(10);
    DEFER(log_free(a), {
        char* b = log_malloc(20);
        DEFER(log_free(b), {
            char* c = log_malloc(30);
            DEFER(log_free(c), {})
        })
    });
}
```

This gets the job done and saves the need for `PRE_DEFER` and `POST_DEFER` macros. However, it is not compatible with my original macro's syntax. Also, it leads to nesting that was hidden in my original version, as the remainder of the function needs to be passed into the `DEFER` macro.

For the sake of completeness, I am including the gcc/clang attribute((cleanup)) version of the code. It is as follows:

```
#define DEFER(type, name, init_func, fini_func_name) \
    type name __attribute__ ((__cleanup__(fini_func_name))) = init_func

void* log_malloc(size_t size) {
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    printf("Allocated %zu bytes: %p\n", size, ptr);
    return ptr;
}

void log_free(char** ptr) {
    free(*ptr);
    printf("Freed %p\n", *ptr);
}

int test() {
    DEFER(char*, a, log_malloc(10), log_free);
    DEFER(char*, b, log_malloc(20), log_free);
    DEFER(char*, c, log_malloc(30), log_free);
    return 0;
}
```

This of course requires yet another syntax for the macro that is incompatible with both the original version and the MSVC extension version. It also requires an awkward syntax that wraps and splits up the creation function call.

An ideal solution would reconcile all of these versions (vanilla C and various compiler extensions) into a single syntax for cross-platform sake.

Comment: MSVC/Win32 has its own approach: Structured Exception Handling (SEH): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp

Comment: What do you have in mind when you say _"the destructor logic becomes implicit"_?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a dynamic resize of the tables. Instead, if you have more than 32 cleanups in a single function, perhaps it is time to start a new function?

Comment: In a single threaded function though, these defers will execute as part of the function. If you are looking for a way to do cleanup after the function has returned, you can create and then detach a new thread inside the function. It's generally only worth doing though if there's rather a lot of cleanup work to do. You also have to be careful about the scope of the variables the thread uses so important variables don't go out of scope before the thread finishes.

Comment: @Dai. Thanks for pointing me to that link! I see I can sort of accomplish what I want usng `__try` and `__finally`. However, I am having trouble making it work with multiple defer statements (as this would requiring nesting the remainder of the body of the function within the try block). Will update the question with this attempt shortly.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon _"as this would requiring nesting the remainder of the body of the function within the try block"_ - well, yes, that's exactly how `try/finally` is meant to be used - though I agree it can make code messier...

Comment: @TedLyngmo All I mean by that is the destructor would need to be implemented as part of a cpp class (along with constructor and copy/move functions) as part of a "rule of 5". These function calls are not explicitly written at the callee site, so it would be easy to not recognize the cost of the destructor.

Comment: @BoP Fair point. > 32 cleanups would certainly be a pathologic case! I could always provide `PRE_DEFER_N(n)` and `PRE_DEFER()` versions of the macro to let the user choose.

Comment: @SimonGoater The limitation of having the destructor called in the same scope is fine by me. I would rather not spin up a thread and have the destructor called at some other point outside of the function, even if it provides some flexibility. That could serve a different use case for sure though. It would be very different than go's `defer` keyword behavior anyways.

Comment: @Dai The messiness was what I had hoped to avoid :) If I do use the SEH approach, it is hard to make it compatible with the gcc/clang extension version of the code or the original version I has posted. I added all three versions to the question.

Comment: FWIW, I question the validity of even doing this in the first place. Why not simply delete the pointer (in this case) immediately when done with it? - that way memory could potentially be reused. I don't quite get what the benefit is of all this added complexity.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon You don't have to make it that complicated. Just store a lambda or similar and call it in the destructor. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xs3ra1xj1)

Comment: @TedLyngmo That is very neat, thanks! I am sure there must be a way to allow this lambda to accept a single passed in variable parameter though, right (I guess it has something to do with a capture group)? The fact that the destructor is called in this case at the scope end rather than function end with the lambda is fine as well (probably even preferable).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Yes, you can capture by reference or value if you want and yes, it'll be called when it goes out of scope. Of course, when working with C++ you'd probably make every resource into a RAII wrapper and then the `at_exit` class template wouldn't even be needed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Using your code I came up with [this wrapper macro](https://godbolt.org/z/esc6hqW5q). It preserves the syntax I want while getting rid of the PRE_DEFER and POST_DEFER stuff from my original version. Really wanted to stick to C instead of C++, but I suppose I can use this wrapped up option and compile it separately as a helper library whlie keeping the rest of the code compiling with a C compiler.

Comment: If you want to manage raw owning pointers, there's already a class for that (`unique_ptr`) [example](https://godbolt.org/z/hTbc8obPa)

Comment: `unique_ptr` is certainly great for use in C++, but is also a good example of how the destructor becomes implicit (i.e. there is no mention of `log_free` within `func()`). `unique_ptr` (or even the lambda solution) unfortunately cannot be wrapped for use in C however. When I wrap them in the extern "C" block, I would need to wrap the destructor into an explicit function, which would then need to be called manually in the C code that uses the unique_ptr/lambda indirectly. That would of course defeat the purpose of making such a wrapper.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon _"no mention of `log_free` within `func()`"_  - No, the `log_malloc` function returns a `unique_ptr` which has a call to `log_free` baked in. _"unfortunately cannot be wrapped for use in C "_ - If you go with a C++ solution, you can wrap all C calls and resources in RAII wrappers. It's usually pretty straight forward and then you have all the resource handling safety you need.

Comment: The correct way to do things in C is to handle this in application logic. The outermost API function of your library does the resource allocation and de-allocation, and in between in calls an internal (likely inlined) function which is the actual algorithm. This solves clean-up and error handling, while at the same time applying proper OO - don't mix invarious unrelated stuff such as allocation into the actual algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> has about a 10% performance overhead.

Most likely this arises because of calling cleanup functions indirectly.  The compiler cannot optimize indirect calls as well as it can direct ones.

> it is limited in the number of `DEFER` macro calls that can be handled.

Yes and no.  Your implementation has a limit to the number of `DEFER` calls per `PRE_DEFER`, but you could put multiple `PRE_DEFER`s in the same function by nesting them within blocks.  Or by providing a distinguishing label for each one, which you then use to form the names of the variables containing the wanted information. Of course, each `PRE_DEFER` requires its own `POST_DEFER`, too.

> Is there a way to programmatically populate the size of the defers array (as a VLA) in the generated macro code?

Not ahead of the the appearance of the `DEFER` calls, no.

You could consider something more like this:

```
#define DEFER(cleanup) for (_Bool done_ = 0; !done_; (cleanup), done_ = 1)
```

That defers evaluation of the expression given by the argument to `DEFER` until after completion of the next statement, which can be, but does not need to be, a compound one.  You would use it similarly to your `__try` / `__finally` example, but the syntax is a bit less fraught:

```
void test() {
    char* a = log_malloc(10);
    DEFER(log_free(a)) {
        char* b = log_malloc(20);
        DEFER(log_free(b)) {
            char* c = log_malloc(30);
            DEFER(log_free(c));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by ...

> An ideal solution would reconcile all of these versions (vanilla C and various compiler extensions) into a single syntax for cross-platform sake.

... but the above uses only standard C99 features.  It will work with any C99 or later implementation.

---

Honorable mention: [`pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html). These are not only standard C, but standardized themselves -- but by POSIX, not by the C language.  They will work in conjunction with a pthreads implementation, but not more broadly.

Comment: Thanks! Your macro is probably the most practical approach with minimal boilerplate for a pure C-only solution. Clever use of the for loop. Shame about the braces, but I guess it better shows the scope of each defer and makes sure that the allocations are freed as early as possible rather than at the end of the function call.